# How can I send a soap request using flutter with two arguments and a wsdl

Tags: flutter, dart, soap, request, wsdl

I am trying to send a soap request with two arguments using flutter.
The wsdl can be found at [this address](https://info802-serveur-soap.herokuapp.com/pricecalculator?wsdl)

I didn't found any ways to only send a request with two arguments. I saw some comments on a different post using the http package but it doesn't really answer my question.

What I need is, being able to send a request with a "country" and a "weight" argument, at the link above, and it'll return the price.

NB : I'm relatively new to flutter

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you need to send get or post request to this url so you may need to use one of these libraries either [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) or [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) i usually use dio for this
and to send get request for this link for example like below

```
    Response response = await Dio().get("https://info802-serveur-soap.herokuapp.com/pricecalculator?wsdl&country=egypt&weight=10");
```

this for get request

and for post request you can use this

```
response = await dio.post("/test", data: {"country": "egypt", "weight": "10"});
```

i hope this useful for you
and also you can make a delete , patch , update requests using dio

Comment: what should we replace with "/test" in post

Comment: the url you want to post to any url you need just like this
https://info802-serveur-soap.herokuapp.com/pricecalculator?wsdl&country=egypt&weight=10

but with the url you need to post to